# Leave Variables in Memory After Execution

Tags: python, shell

In Matlab, when you run a script, variables stick around in memory and you have access in the shell.  I find this really useful for debugging and exploring.  I'm trying to achieve a similar effect in Python.  Maybe this is not even possible.

As an example, suppose I have a file named `script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def foo(n):
    return 2*n

x = 5
y = foo(5)
```

I want to be able to run this and have access to `x` and `y` in a python shell.  I tried `>>> import script` which gives me access to `foo` via `script.foo()`, but I want access to `x` and `y` too.

`>>> from script import *` does not get the job done either.

How do I make python leave these (in memory) in a python shell for me?

Comment: By shell, do you mean linux shell? or Python REPL?

Comment: @thefourtheye: I want a python shell, in a linux terminal.  I would be satisfied with any sane and simple way to get it to work, actually. I never heard of REPL.  Is that how the regular python shell works, or a different way to run things?

Comment: [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) is for Read, Evaluate, Print Loop — many command interpreters work in roughly this way.  Python compiles scripts, but runs as a REPL when you don't tell it which script to run.

Comment: Thank you, I learned something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is by running your script with the `-i` flag (which stands for "inspect interactively").

```
python -i my_script.py
```

The script will run and then the Python shell prompt `>>>` will be shown, allowing you to interact with the variables that the script created.

Another good option would be to install [IPython](http://ipython.org/), which adds some extra features to the basic Python shell. Within an IPython session, you can call

```
%run my_script.py
```

to get the same effect. IPython should be available in your Linux distro's repositories.

Comment: The `-i` flag was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks to ooga too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) module to enter the debugger at any particular point. For instance:

```
import pdb

def foo(n):
    pdb.set_trace()  # <-- enters debugger here
    return 2*n

x = 5
y = foo(5)
```